# Command Prompt extract jpg files with full path

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I need a batch command to list all files (with extension **.Jpg, .Txt**) here is one command

```
dir /r /s /b
```

**output of command:**

```
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\news.mp4
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\speech.mp3
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\namo.apk
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\n1.txt
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\new.txt
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\new2.html
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\new3.png
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\web\new3.js
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\web\index.html
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\web\background.jpg
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\web\banner.jpg
...
...
```

But I want **output** something like this:

```
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\web\background.jpg
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\web\banner.jpg
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\n1.txt
C:\Users\vb3\Desktop\docs\new.txt
```

without if else statement is there any way to filter path of only **jpg** and **txt** files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `where /R`ecursive:

```bat
where/r . *.jpg *.txt
```

And one using `For /R` loop:

```bat
for /r  %i in (*.jpg *.txt)do @echo=%i
```

---

In PowerShell:

```bat
'*.txt','*.jpg' |ls -Re | Select -ExP FullName
```

---

- Some further reading:

  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
  - **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**
  - **[Where](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**
  - **[Select-Object | Select](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)**
  - **[Get-ChildItem | dir | ls |gci](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command:

```
dir /s /b *.jpg *.txt
```

I'm not sure why you were interested in alternate datastreams, but if that is also a requirement, then you can obviously use this:

```
dir /s /r /b *.jpg *.txt
```